# not able to get subcategory of particular category in mvc 4 and designing issue of category and subcategory model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am working on help desk system in mvc.

i have only one master table for user and technicians.

this is my category class:

```
 public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> subCategory { get; set; }//category can have more than 1 category
    }
```

This is my Subcategory:

```
public class SubCategory
    {
          [Key]
          public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
          public string Name { get; set; }
          public int CategoryId { get; set; }
          public virtual ICollection<TicketInfo> ticketsInfo { get; set; }/to keep track of all tickets under this particular subcategory.
          public virtual ICollection<UserDetails> technicianInfo { get; set; }//to keep track of technician and user under this subcategory.

          public virtual Category category { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my usermaster(it defines both user and technician)

```
public class UserDetails
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        public virtual SubCategory subCategory { get; set; }

    }
```

now when i am firing dis query::

```
public list<Category> FetchTicketDetailsforSubcategory(int categoryId)
        {
            using (HelpDeskdbContext context = new HelpDeskdbContext())
            {
                var category = from temp in context.Category where                temp.CategoryId == categoryId select temp;

                return category;
            }   
        }
```

it just show me the category but not subcategory under that category.

it show me this on subcategory:**The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

can any one figure out what is wrong with my class design??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
context.Category.Where(x=>x.CategoryId == categoryId).SelectMany(x=>x.subCategory).ToList()
```