# cant assign datatable value to list of class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Model:

```
public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            SubCategory = new List<SubCategory>();
            TicketsInfo = new List<TicketInfo>();
            UserDetails = new List<UserDetails>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public List<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; } //subcategory is my another class
        public List<TicketInfo> TicketsInfo { get; set; }//ticketinfo is my another class
        public List<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }//userdetails is my another class
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
DataTable categoryDetailsforTickets = categoriesBal.FetchTicketDetailsforSubcategory(categoryId);
            List<Category> categoryModelforTickets = new List<Category>();

            if (categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Category categoryModel = new Category();
                    categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].TicketId =(int) categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i].ItemArray[i];
                    categoryModel.UserDetails[i].FName = categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i].ItemArray[i].ToString();
                    categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].Subject = categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i].ItemArray[i].ToString();
                    categoryModelforTickets.Add(categoryModel);
                }
            }
```

but it is throwing me error on this line:

```
categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].TicketId =(int) categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i].ItemArray[i];
```

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

there are two records coming in my datatable.

can anybody figure out what is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify column also here :

```
 categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].TicketId =(int)categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i][0];
```

OR

```
categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].TicketId =(int)categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows[i]["coloumnname"];
```

OR

Try iterating datatable as :-

```
foreach (DataRow row in categoryDetailsforTickets.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
  categoryModel.TicketsInfo[i].TicketId =(int)row["coloumnname"];
  ........
}
```

Comment: @priyankavashi..don't use ItemArray just try above code only

Comment: ya i have tried your both solution bt it is still throwing me same error

Comment: @priyankavashi..just see columnname in your dataset and use instead of "coloumnnane" in second answer

Comment: yaa i have done that bt same problem.i think problem is different

Comment: @priyankavashi...very strange..its giving same error??

Comment: can i ask u for 1 help if it is k with u??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498817/not-able-to-get-subcategory-of-particular-category-in-mvc-4-and-designing-issue?rq=1

Comment: that i dont know bt when i have kept ur updated ans it worked bt plz do provide me solution for that question if possible.plz

Comment: yeah sure and i should be thankful to you.u shouldnt be thankful to me.